# Maximum likelihod estimator formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an i.i.d sample from the parametric family of distributions $\mathcal{P} = \{P_\theta: \theta \in \Theta \subset \mathbb{R}^k\}$, $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is some realization of $\mathbf{X}$.
There is a widely known formula for the ML-estimate:
$$\hat\theta(\mathbf{x}) = \underset{\theta \in \Theta}{\operatorname{argmax}} L(\mathbf{x}; \theta)$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is fixed and does not depend on $\theta$.

But could we use the following formula $$\hat\theta(\mathbf{X}) = \underset{\theta \in \Theta}{\operatorname{argmax}} L(\mathbf{X}; \theta) $$
to find ML-estimator $\hat\theta(\mathbf{X})$? I am concerned about the fact that random vector $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ implicitly depends on $\theta$ because $X_i \sim P_\theta$ whereas in the first formula vector $\mathbf{x}$ doesn't depend on $\theta$.

Comment: It’s unclear what you mean here. “Little” x in the above formula also depends on $\theta$ as your observations are also drawn from a distribution parametrized by $\theta$—I’m not sure I see the difference between the first and second rewritings of the MLE.

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris I mean $\mathbf{x}$ here is a fixed constant that doesn't vary when we change $\theta$ as argument of the likelihood function. I think you can always take any fixed $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that doesn't even belong to the support of $\mathbf{X}$ and consider it as some realization of $\mathbf{X}$ (in case of the discrete distribution it will have zero probability, it is not prohibited).

Comment: The idea is that your data is “something you are given.” In other words, the MLE formulation is that you have some set of observations whose distribution depends on the $\theta$ you’re optimizing over, and you wish to find the distribution that best “explains” the observations. If $X$ is a random variable in the general process it’s not clear what this likelihood would even evaluate to, or what this framework even means.

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris So you mean the second formula is technically incorrect? I saw some sources where it is used. For example [formula "6" here](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/maximum-likelihood#hid4). Also see this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments#Description) article about GMM (formula for $\hat \theta$). It has similar structure with the formula above (argmin of random variables that depends on the unknown parameter). Are these two sources wrong?

Comment: Note that $Y_t$ in the Wikipedia article are observations, which are fixed in the minimization. In general, they are random variables whose distribution depends on $\theta$ (like your little $x$ above), but they are treated as constants in the minimization process.

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris I think that is the point - if we want to use the above formula for $\theta(\mathbf{X})$ then we **must** treat random variables as constants in the minimization process!

Comment: Than, I’m afraid I’m not sure what you are asking for, since I don’t understand the difference between both cases.

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris in the first formula $\mathbf{x}$ is a fixed numerical vector, $L(\mathbf{x}, \theta)$ is a typical likelihood function and $\hat \theta(\mathbf{x})$ is the **estimate**. In the second formula $\mathbf{X}$ is a random vector, $L(\mathbf{X}, \theta)$ is a random variable which is obtained from $L(\mathbf{x}, \theta)$ by substituting $\mathbf{X}$ on place of $\mathbf{x}$, $\hat \theta(\mathbf{X})$ is the **estimator**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77767/discussion-between-guillermo-angeris-and-rodvi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a [random vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable) is defined as a mapping from the sample space to Euclidean space --- that is, your random vector $\mathbf{X}: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ maps each outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ to a real vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  This object **does not** depend on $\theta$, but its probability distribution does depend on $\theta$.  (This is an important distinction - it means that the random variable is well-defined independently of the parameter $\theta$.  It is merely a real vector description of each outcome in the sample space.)

The equation for the MLE takes an argument $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ which is a data vector, and maps this to an output $\hat{\theta}(\mathbf{x}) \in \Theta$ which is the corresponding estimate formed via maximisation of the likelihood.$^\dagger$  The maximum-likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}(\mathbf{X})$ involves substitution of the random variable $\mathbf{X}$ into the argument of the MLE function, which implicitly forms a random variable by [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) (i.e., this random variable is a function of another random variable, which is itself a function).  Putting these together, we get the function composition $\hat{\theta}(\mathbf{X}) = \hat{\theta} \circ \mathbf{X}$ which means that we now have a mapping (showing the intermediate set):

$$\hat{\theta}(\mathbf{X}): \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Theta.$$

This means that the maximum-likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}(\mathbf{X})$ is a mapping from the sample space to the parameter space, which means that it is a random variable on the parameter space.  This random variable also **does not** depend on $\theta$ in a functional sense, since it is a mapping from the sample space.  As with the observed data, its *probability distribution* depends on $\theta$, through the distribution of the data vector.

---

$^\dagger$ Even this involves a slight abuse of terminology, since $\arg \max$ technically refers to the *set* of maximising values in the optimisation.  We assume that there is a unique maximising parameter for any data input in the problem at hand, and we take the $\arg \max$ to be this unique parameter, not the singleton set containing that parameter.  This is a common "abuse of notation" that is used when working with $\arg \max$ definitions.